# Use of Index and Match function with Count/Counta/Countif to count the results on a 3rd wookbok

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have great success in guidance from the experts on Stack. I need guidance once more. :)

I have workbook 1 that has a copy of names on column A and email addresses on column B. Workbook 2 that has copy of names on A and email addresses on column B and data that I need copied on Column c on workbook 2.

I have a workbook 3 in which I would like to use to build a table with matched and counted from the formula I need. Below I will show.

workbook 1 pic:
[image]

Workbook 2 pic:
[image]

Workbook 3 pic:
[image]

Ultimately, I wanted the index,matched and counted total to show up on the basic table shown on workbook 3. As you can see there are 4 email addresses that match between work book 1 and workbook 2, but there are also 4 email addresses that do not match. after the matching and unmatching is found, i want the formula to give me the count of the matched and unmatched from column c in workbook 2.

so if you just use your eyes and count, you will see that rows 2 through 4 these email addresses matched between work book 1 and work book 2. that would give me a total of 2 drinks expenses and 2 food expenses from the matching found, but also give me 2 tickets expenses and 2 parking expenses from the unmatched found.

Comment: Why make us reproduce your data to test formula?  Post the data directly as text in the Original Post so all we need to do is copy and paste, it will help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Matched:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!A:A,'Sheet2'!$A$2:$A$100,'Sheet1'!B:B,'Sheet2'!$B$2:$B$100)>0)*('Sheet2'!$C$2:$C$100=$B3))
```

For the unMatched

```
=SUMPRODUCT((COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!A:A,'Sheet2'!$A$2:$A$100,'Sheet1'!B:B,'Sheet2'!$B$2:$B$100)=0)*('Sheet2'!$C$2:$C$100=$B7))
```

These are untested as I did not want to retype that much data, but in thoery should work.

Comment: That did the trick after changing it up a little for my usage. Thanks! @Scott Craner